# How do I prevent React Router 4 from re-rendering on URL switch?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-redux

I am having a hard time trying to **preventing** React Router 4.1.2 (latest) from restting my forms when I am switching the tabs in my application.

Here's my structure:

Root component:

```
<Route path="/" component={Content}/>
```

Content component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {Redirect, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom'
import {history} from 'configureStore'
import * as actions from 'actions/tabs';
import {Divider, Input} from 'semantic-ui-react'
import Tabs from 'components/Tabs'
import Dashboard from 'components/Dashboard'
import ProfileList from 'components/ProfileList'

class Content extends Component {
  render() {
    const {tabs, switchTab, closeTab} = this.props
    let componentByName = {
      Dashboard: Dashboard,
      ProfileForm: ProfileForm,
      ProfileList: ProfileList
    }
    let routes = []

    tabs.forEach((tab) => {
        routes.push(<Route key={tab.id} exact path={tab.path} component={componentByName[tab.component]}/>)
    })

    return (
      <div>
        <Tabs list={tabs} onClick={switchTab} onCloseClick={closeTab}/>

        <Divider hidden/>

        <Switch>
          {routes}
        </Switch>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  tabs: state.tabs
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(Content)
```

How can I just hide/show the content without losing anything from the tabs I switch from?

Answer (score 0):

You can use store to keep your data. All your tab's data will be connecting to a store. Even you switch the tab the data in the store will not be lost. So next time you render the tab you have the data that was in previous render.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I get what you are saying conceptually but how do I actually implement that? Do I save the component's state on componentWillUnmount? Do I serialize the entire component? I am completely lost.

Answer (score 0):

You can render out all your tabs and switching between your tabs can by handled just by toggling active/unactive classes

```
<div className={history.location.pathname === '/path' && "active"}>
  <!-- your form or anything -->
</div>
```

Or if you really want to be rerendering the form, you should follow @Sudarshan and use Controlled component https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components